# Como enviar un objeto dentro de un objeto en postman

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, webservice, backend, postman

Hola tengo el siguiente modelo

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const Schema = mongoose.Schema
const MonstruoSchema =  Schema ({
     name:String,
     item:[{
         arma:String
      }]
})
module.exports = mongoose.model ("Monstruo",MonstruoSchema);
```

el cual es un objeto Monstruo que contiene una array de items llamados arma, mi intencion es tener un monstruo el cual pueda tener una lista de n armas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estoy intentando agregarle un arma a través de postman de la siguiente manera pero no he logrado que se agregue el item como tengo pensado

```
app.post("/api/monstruo",(req,res) => {
let monstruo = new Monstruo()

monstruo.name = req.body.name
monstruo.item.nombre= req.body.nombre

monstruo.save((err,monstruoGuardado)=>{ 
    if (err) res.status(500).send("no se guardo bienn")
    res.status(200).send({monstruo:monstruoGuardado})
})
```

})

Comment: El código debe ir en formato texto y no en imagen. Por favor haz clic en [edit] y corrige tu pregunta. Saludos

Comment: oh lo lamento, creo que ahora quedo como debia